# Replace certain string if it has a matching string after it?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string like this:

```
this'is'my'
test'
string'
```

I need to do a Find and Replace prefer using Regex, on the '.

I need to replace ' with '\r\n, but not the change the other lines which already have the line spacing, basically make it look like this:

```
this'
is'
my'
test'
string'
```

I can't remove all the "\r\n"'s and then change them all, as i need this to be quick and only change what is needed to be changed.

Currently i am doing this:

```
var EscapeCharactor = "?"
var LineEndCharactor = "'"

string result = Regex.Replace(data, @"(([^\" + EscapeCharactor + "]" + LineEndCharactor + @"[^\r\n|^\r|^\n])|(\" + EscapeCharactor + @"\" + EscapeCharactor + LineEndCharactor + "[^\r\n|^\r|^\n]))", "$1\r\n");
return ediDataUnWrapped;
```

But it is creating this:

```
this'i
s'm
y'
test'
string'
```

Is this possible to only alter certain ones and not include the extra letter or am i going to have to manage with removing all the \r\n's and then adding it to all of them?

Comment: Better rename that `char` variable. It's confusing.

Comment: My Code is named properly, I just did that for the example, but i will change it in this as well so it makes more sense for people reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-regex approach:

```
string testString = @"this'is'my'
test'
string'";

var split = testString.Split(new[]{"'"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim() + "'");
testString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, split);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked Perfectly and it was twice as fast as mine which did not even work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex (Tim's solution looks nicer)

```
    string test = "this'is'my'test'\r\nstring'";

    test = Regex.Replace(test,@"[\r\n]","");
    Regex rgx = new Regex("(\\w')([\\\\r]?[\\\\n]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var rep = rgx.Replace(test,"$0\r\n");

    Console.WriteLine(rep);
```

Results in

```
this'
is'
my'
test'
string'
```

//KH

Comment: I agree that his looked better. Also this one did not work fully for me, if the ' has whitespace before it, then it did not add the linebreak.

Comment: Well white spaces are just a tweak away I guess, but if Tims work for you I would go with that one, for future work with regexp this site is great for testing regex syntax http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution with two simples `String.Replace()` :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "this'is'my'test'\r\nstring'\r\n";
        s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty); // remove /r/n
        s = s.Replace("'", "'" + Environment.NewLine); // replace ' by ' + /r/n
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
this'
is'
my'
test'
string'
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I edited the snippet. Now I kept it. Love yours by the way. Sexiest than mine and you remove whitespace. I upvoted it.